# How to set different css for different pages without changing HTML (Angular 4+)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using one HTML which has a nav bar, but the navbar in page2 has different text color. I don't want to make two different divs for each page.

Currently, what I am doing is:

```
<div *ngIf="headerType !== 'page1'">
....
</div>
```

```
<div *ngIf="headerType == 'page1'">
....
</div>
```

I would like to just change the font-color, without copy/pasting two separate bodies. How can I do this in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ngStyle`, You can do something like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':headerType  === 'page1' ? 'green' : 'red' }"></<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can define component specific CSS/Sass files in your component.ts file
Like: 
`@Component({
    selector: 'app-browse',
    templateUrl: './browse.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./browse.component.css'],
})`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a parameter (can be a boolean variable from ts for example) to determine on which page you are and then bind it to ngClass.
something like this for example:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'first': first, 'second': !first}">My  Nav<div>
```

hope it helped.